# POST Request to fetch stripe credentials with Cloud Function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm currently using Cloud Functions as my backend for a mobile app. I've got basic payments working with Stripe with cloud functions programmed with node.js. I've been following the documentation here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#token-request

I've got step 3, the redirect working, so I have the code.

Step 4 is the issue for me. Stripe says that step 4 is to "Fetch user credentials from Stripe". It says we can make a POST request to Stripe's endpoint to fetch the data and gives this as an example:

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
  -d code="{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}" \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

(I've obviously removed my client_secret key here). I have no idea what to do with the above.

How do I Fetch this data with a post call? My current function looks like this and is able to fetch the first authorization code from step 3. I have yet to successfully implement Step 4 in this function as well to complete the sign up:

Thank you so much.

```
exports.registerUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }

    return cors(req, res, () => {
        let scope = req.query.scope;
        let authCode = req.query.code;
        let state = req.query.state;
        let error = req.query.error; 

        console.log('Scope: ', scope);
        console.log('Authorization Code: ', authCode);
        console.log('Error: ', error);

        //Shows authCode from Step 3
        res.status(200).send(authCode);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're making the call from server side, you can use packages like `request`, `node-fetch` etc to make post call to given url

Comment: you can make use of stripe-node https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/b5fb564df2f7a08021bc8be9bb31cc964900fa0b/lib/resources/OAuth.js#L38 to complete step 4. 
Use `OAuth.token()` function to complete step 4